# Can i call One Visual force page into another Visual force page which is in PDF

Tags: visualforce, managed-package, quote

I have a Installed Package as "ForecastTrac " in my org Sandbox .It has a custom object as "Opportunity Forecast" and Visual force pages created based on standard controller.Now i have created a Visual force page on "Quote Object " in a PDF format.I have quered on all the standard and custom objects .Now i would like to get this "Opportunity Forecast" fields.So tried using the wrapper class and called out the field.The issue is the field values  of opportunity forecast is not getting displayed,while rest of the standard objects and custom objects values are displayed when the record is created . when i click the link of Visual Force page , it  displays all the values except the "Opportunity Forecast" Object Values.Any suggestion Plz.

Answer (score 3):

Visualforce pages cannot reach out of their namespace using `apex:include` or `apex:composition` (this applies to both managed packages and the unmanaged `c` context)

To do this we must leverage either a data model relation, or a global Visualforce Component, or an Apex controller class that pulls in the rendered page using `PageReference.getContent()`

Comment: :Can i get some example on this